# How can I make the height of row depend on columns in react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I came across a problem while creating a responsive grid using react-bootstrap. I'm doing the following to create a responsive layout where the number of columns in a single row keeps decreasing from 6 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 as the browser width decreases.

The problem with this approach is that the height of the row is set. If I don't set it to anything, the columns are flat and I can't set the column height to anything. If I give the row h-100, however, each "row" in the Row are far too spaced out (see the screenshot attached).

Is there a good way to control the height of the Row based on that of Col? I've been looking this up for a few days but haven't been able to find anything.

[image: Screenshot of the grid]

```js
<Container fluid>
      <Row
        xs={2}
        sm={2}
        md={3}
        lg={4}
        xl={6}
        className="p-0 m-0 g-0"
      >
        <Col className="object-panel">1</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">2</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">3</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">4</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">5</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">6</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">7</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">8</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">9</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">10</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">11</Col>
        <Col className="object-panel">12</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```